Split image file in lines from ALTO groundtruth coordinates for TrOCR
I want to train a model for TrOCR. I have a personal transcribed groundtruth (ALTO). TrOCR only works with lines and not full pages so I need to crop the image files in lines with the coordinates from the ALTO files and match them with the transcription. My code:
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from collections import Counter

images=os.listdir("./img")
xmls=os.listdir("./alto")

def correct_xy(xy):
    xx=sorted(xy)
    if len(xy)<21:
        l=len(xx)
        missing=21-l
        c=Counter(np.random.choice(range(l-1),missing))
        for i in range(l-1):
            x=np.linspace(xx[i][0],xx[i+1][0],c[i]+2,dtype=int)[1:-1]
            y=np.linspace(xx[i][1],xx[i+1][1],c[i]+2,dtype=int)[1:-1]
            if len(x):
                xx+=list(map(list,zip(x,y)))
        return xx
        if len(xy)>21:
            new_xy=[0]*21
            new_xy[0]=xx[0]
            step=(len(xx)-2)/19
            for i in range(1,20):
                new_xy[i]=xx[int(np.floor(i*step))]
            new_xy[-1]=xx[-1]
            return new_xy
        return xx

def get_polygon(xys,boxes,i,margin=[20]*4):
    U,D,R,L = margin
    X,Y,H,W = boxes[i]
    
    curr=sorted(xys[i])
    curr[0][0]-=L
    curr[-1][0]+=R
    curr=[[x[0],x[1]+D] for x in curr]
    
    if i == 0:
        prev=[[x[0],x[1]-H] for x in curr]
    else:
        prev=sorted(xys[i-1])
        prev=sorted([[curr[0][0],prev[0][1]]]+prev+[[curr[-1][0],prev[-1][1]]])
        
        for l in range(len(prev)):
            if prev[1][0]==curr[0][0]:
                break
        for r in range(len(prev)):
            if prev[r][0]==curr[-1][0]:
                break
                
        prev=prev[l:r+1]
        if prev[0]==prev[1]:
            prev=prev[1:]
            
        prev=[[x[0],x[1]+U] for x in prev]
        
        gap=min(curr)[1]-min(prev)[1]-H
        
        if gap > 0:
            prev=[[x[0],x[1]+gap] for x in prev]
            
    return list(map(tuple,prev[::-1]+curr))
    
text = []
prefix='{http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4#}'
for file_image, file_xml in zip(sorted([img[:-4] for img in images]),sorted([xm[:-4] for xm in xmls])):
    assert file_image == file_xml
    path_img="./img/"+file_image+".jpg"
    path_xml="./alto/"+file_xml+".xml"
    
    tree = ET.parse(path_xml)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    img = Image.open(path_img).convert('L').point(lambda x : 255 if x > 200 else 0, mode='1')
    
    xys = {} #coordinates
    boxes = {}
    to_del = []
    for i, element in enumerate(root.iter(prefix+'String')):
        #texts
        txt = [path_img+"_"+str(i).zfill(2)+".png",element.get("CONTENT")]
        if txt[-1]=="":
            to_del += [i]
            continue
        text.append(txt)
        
    for i,element in enumerate(root.iter(prefix+'TextLine')):
        #images
        boxes[i] = tuple([int(element.get(s)) for s in ['HPOS','VPOS','HEIGHT','WIDTH']])
        xy = [element.get(s) for s in ['BASELINE']][0].split(' ')
        xys[i]=correct_xy([list(map(int,s.split(','))) for s in xy])
        
    for i in to_del:
        del xys[i]
        del boxes[i]
        
    for i in xys.keys():
        polygon = get_polygon(xys,boxes,i=i,margin=[10,20,50,50])
        
        mask = Image.new("L", img.size, 0)
        background = Image.new("L", img.size, 255)
        draw = ImageDraw(mask)
        draw.polygon(polygon, fill="white", outline=None)
        result = Image.composite(img, background, mask)
        
        (X, Y, W, H) = cv2.boundingRect(np.array(polygon))
        result = result.crop([X, Y, X + W, Y + H])
        
        result.save('./lines/'+file_image+"_"+str(i).zfill(2)+'.png')

I got this error and I don't see anything wrong with my code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/incognito/TrOCR-py3.10/LINES/alto2lines.py", line 95, in <module>
    xys[i]=correct_xy([list(map(int,s.split(','))) for s in xy])
  File "/home/incognito/TrOCR-py3.10/LINES/alto2lines.py", line 19, in correct_xy
    y=np.linspace(xx[i][1],xx[i+1][1],c[i]+2,dtype=int)[1:-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

A sample of my ALTO xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alto xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4#"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4# http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/v4/alto-4-2.xsd">
  <Description>
    <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
    <sourceImageInformation>
      <fileName>1.jpg</fileName>
    </sourceImageInformation>
  </Description>
  <Tags>
    <OtherTag ID="BT1" LABEL="Title" DESCRIPTION="block type Title"/><OtherTag ID="BT2" LABEL="Main" DESCRIPTION="block type Main"/><OtherTag ID="BT3" LABEL="Commentary" DESCRIPTION="block type Commentary"/><OtherTag ID="BT4" LABEL="Illustration" DESCRIPTION="block type Illustration"/><OtherTag ID="BT35" LABEL="text" DESCRIPTION="block type text"/>
    <OtherTag ID="LT46" LABEL="default" DESCRIPTION="line type default"/>
  </Tags>
  <Layout>
    <Page WIDTH="2579"
          HEIGHT="2837"
          PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="0"
          ID="eSc_dummypage_">
      <PrintSpace HPOS="0"
                  VPOS="0"
                  WIDTH="2579"
                  HEIGHT="2837">
        <TextBlock HPOS="580"
                   VPOS="334"
                   WIDTH="1940"
                   HEIGHT="2230"
                   ID="eSc_textblock_2aa65984"
                   TAGREFS="BT2">
          <Shape><Polygon POINTS="2074 334 2489 353 2520 691 2495 762 2476 2532 2451 2558 2306 2564 617 2558 580 906 605 378 712 353 818 371 2074 334"/></Shape>
          <TextLine ID="eSc_line_48be6c40"
                    TAGREFS="LT46"
                    BASELINE="627 397 964 397 1713 373 2473 373"
                    HPOS="625"
                    VPOS="338"
                    WIDTH="1848"
                    HEIGHT="87">
            <Shape><Polygon POINTS="2470 351 2454 351 2438 349 2422 349 2407 348 2391 348 2375 346 2359 346 2344 345 2328 345 2312 343 2296 343 2281 343 2274 342 2254 345 2184 338 2183 338 2181 338 2158 349 2156 349 2139 349 1986 342 1984 342 1983 342 1959 349 1868 338 1855 340 1839 340 1823 340 1808 342 1792 342 1776 342 1775 342 1700 346 1655 345 1650 346 1634 346 1618 346 1603 346 1587 348 1571 348 1555 348 1540 349 1524 349 1508 349 1492 351 1477 351 1461 351 1445 351 1429 353 1414 353 1398 353 1382 354 1366 354 1350 354 1335 356 1319 356 1303 356 1287 356 1272 357 1256 357 1240 357 1224 359 1209 359 1193 359 1179 359 1179 360 1161 365 966 365 956 367 941 367 925 367 909 368 893 368 878 368 862 370 846 370 830 370 815 370 799 368 788 365 646 365 641 368 625 370 627 397 627 425 734 423 736 423 780 412 846 420 848 420 1111 419 1112 417 1295 403 1377 409 1379 409 1380 409 1410 400 1741 397 1820 397 1842 406 1844 406 1845 406 1847 406 1886 406 2128 397 2148 401 2159 403 2161 403 2162 403 2167 401 2184 392 2470 395 2473 373 2471 351 2470 351"/></Shape>
            <String CONTENT="את הארון ואת בדיו ואת הכפרת ואת פרכת המסך"
                    HPOS="625"
                    VPOS="338"
                    WIDTH="1848"
                    HEIGHT="87"></String>
          </TextLine>
.... snip

